# Can I move imports to top of file from yasnippet using elisp code?

Tags: yasnippet

I want to add import statements in my yasnippets that go the top of the file (where they will be automatically sorted (or removed if the import already exists)).

```
from subprocess import call # I want this line moved to the top of the 
                            # buffer after snippet expansion

subprocess.call("$0", ${1:shell=True})
```

I want the import statements moved to the top of the file because if the snippet is expanded within a code block, the import statement ends up within the block, and [isort](https://github.com/timothycrosley/isort/) won't be able to sort the import.

Is there any way I can move the import to the top of the file using an elisp snippet within a yasnippet snippet? If so, how do I do it?

(All the elisp yasnippet examples I could find dealt with modifying inserted text, not moving stuff within the buffer after the snippet was expanded...)

Comment: Yes, see `yas-after-exit-snippet-hook` (I'll try to answer my q, but will prolly take some time!)